# Razorpay integration in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift4, xcode10.1

I am facing the problem with the `Razorpay integration`. I have installed the pod `'razorpay' 1.0.6` and after that I found the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay

Reason: image not found
```

I want to integrate `Razorpay`.

Comment: Add Razorpay framework in your embedded binaries. App-> Target -> Embedded Binaries.

Comment: It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong Podspec. Its `razorpay-pod`.

Check this out: https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-pod#installation--docs

Comment: I have installed the pod and followed the steps according to the steps given by the follwing link - "https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/ios-integration/standard/" but i am facing a problem. I am unable to open the Razorpay screen and got the last message in the console as - /Users/travis/build/razorpay/razorpay-ios/RazorpayIOS/CheckoutOtpelf/Classes/RazorpayCheckoutVC.swift deinitialized. Will you please help to solve such issue.